# override variable in template.php with variable from module_preproccess_node

Tags: hooks, theming

I create custom template for node, and put variable in template.php

```
$colors = array('black', 'white');
$variables['group']['color'] = $colors;
$variables['size'] = 'double';
```

then i also create module and want to do hook to node template.

```
mymodule_preproccess_node() {
$colors = array('blue', 'red', 'green');
$variables['group']['color'] = $colors;
$variables['size'] = 'regular';
}
```

i want to show in my result:

```
//colors are blue, red, green instead of black, white
foreach ($group['color'] as $color) {
print $color.', ';
}
//and size is regular instead of double
print $size;
```

am i right? i want to override variables in template.php with variables from my module. then if i disable my module color will back from template.php.

Comment: Hello, and welcome on Drupal Answers. To be clear, the template.php file contains functions; overriding a variable in template.php is not possible, since each function has different variables. There aren't global variables defined in template.php.

Comment: so what i have to do? my aim is
i want to show colors and sise in my custom node template. if my module is enabled then variables taken from mymodule_preproccess_node(), if disabled variables taken from template.php
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding/reverse engineering your question correctly, in your module, you can do something like this:

```
function YOURMODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  if ( // whatever logic ) {

    $colors = array('blue', 'red', 'green');
    $variables['group']['color'] = $colors;
    $variables['size'] = 'regular';

  }

}
```

This will create variables that can be accessed inside node.tpl.php and its variants.

In template.php you can then do something like this:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  if (!isset($variables['size'])) {
    $variables['size'] = 'double';
  }

  if (!isset($variables['group']['color'])) {
    $colors = array('black', 'white');
    $variables['group']['color'] = $colors;
  }

}
```

which will set them to your defaults if they haven't already been set.

Then you can do whatever you want with them in node.tpl.php.